# how can I implement Mosaico into Ember application?

Tags: ember.js, mosaico

I'm beginner Ember developer and now I try to implement [Mosaico.io](https://mosaico.io/) into my Ember application. Previously, I used CKEDITOR. I joined to my index.html file like this:

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.9/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

and then I used create() action in controller for getting text of message like this:

```
create() {
  let model = this.get('model');
  let kind = this.get('model.kind');
  if (kind !== 'sms') {
    model.set('message', CKEDITOR.instances['campaign-content'].getData());
  };
  model.save().then(() => {
    return this.transitionToRoute('campaigns.index');
  });
```

But I don't understand, how can I manage with Mosaico. Does anybody have idea, how can I implement Mosaico into Ember application?